# I can't understand how JavaScript parses this input. Can someone explain it to me?

Tags: javascript, node.js, input

I'm doing a beginner-level programming challenge. I understand the algorithm part, but I don't understand how it takes input.

I know it takes input in three lines. There is some pre-written code that puts the input into an "input" variable. How do I process this "input" variable to get the data in individual lines?

input line 1: number of items ordered, index of item Anna did not eat

input line 2: price of each item

input line 3: cost to Anna

Sample input:

```
4 1

3 10 2 9

12
```

Expected output: `5`

here is my code that is messed up, which I am trying to fix:

```
function processData(input) {

    var input_temp = input.split("\n");
    var allergyIndex = input_temp[0][1];
    var array = input_temp[1].split(" ");
    var annaCharged = input_temp[2];
    var annaMealsCost = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if (i !== allergyIndex){
            annaMealsCost += array[i];
        }
    }

    if (annaMealsCost / 2 === annaCharged){
        console.log("Bon Appetit");
    } else {
        console.log(annaCharged - annaMealsCost / 2);
    } } 

// below is the code that is pre-written, which I don't understand at all:

process.stdin.resume(); process.stdin.setEncoding("ascii");
_input = ""; process.stdin.on("data", function (input) {
    _input += input; });

process.stdin.on("end", function () {    processData(_input); });
```

Comment: STDIO is a method for processes to communicate.  Some other program is going to send your program data via STDIN (standard in).  When that stream sends you data, you need to handle it somehow.  I recommend using a line emitting stream transform.  Perhaps something like this:  https://github.com/jahewson/node-byline

Answer (score 0):

When the program runs, it will listen for the data to be entered in until an `EOF` character. At that point, `processData` will be called with all lines entered up until that point.

If you normally run the program (`node my-program.js`) it will wait for input. You can enter the data, and finally trigger the `process.stdin` `end` event by manually entering `Cmd + D` which will be interpreted as an `EOF` character.

## Piping

Another option is to just put the input as you would enter it into a text file.

By default printing a file will go to `process.stdout`. But you may redirect the print to go to `process.stdin` by using the pipe character (`|`).

**input.txt**

```
4 1

3 10 2 9

12
```

**terminal prompt**

```
cat input.txt | node my-program.js
```

The output of the command `cat input.txt` will be used as input to `node my-program.js`.